# Perda de medalha conquistada

Tags: suporte, medalhas

Tem como perder uma medalha já conquistada?

Por exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu retirar meu voto contra, eu perco essa medalha?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Esse exemplo, como vários outros a medalha é dada para premiar e marcar a pessoa que ela já aprendeu usar determinada funcionalidade. Então se já fez, já aprendeu, se desfez, não desaprendeu, a medalha fica.

Existe um tempo para uma medalha ser concedida, não é imediato, uma vez dada, não é retirada. A não ser por fraude, algum problema técnico do site, ou circunstâncias muito especiais que eu nem saberia citar de tão excepcional que seria. Especialmente as que são indicadores se já fez algo alguma vez.

Só tome o cuidado para não virar *badge hunter* e ficar fazendo coisas só para ganhar a medalha, o objetivo delas não é o seu ganho em si e sim premiar boas ações reais.